# what is meaning of these hadith?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, arabic, arabic-translation

What is meaning and refrece of hadith "la darara walla diraar" as shown in attached photo

[image]

Comment: The Arabic letter "ض" is pronounced as a heavy "d" close to that of "door" it is heavier than "د" which is rather a "d" like in "day"..I wonder why many Turkish and Urdu speakers pronounce it like a "z" which is totally incorrect. While pronouncing a "ظ" like a "z" may be OK. Even if IMO "z" sounds closer to a "ز".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### لا ضرر ولا ضرار
>
> There should be neither harming nor reciprocating harm.

This hadith was recorded in [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/810/2340#p1), [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/2805#p1), [Muwatta Imam Malik](https://sunnah.com/urn/514340), [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/2439), [Sunan Kubra al-Bayhaqi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33024/13137#p1)   etc.